# HHVM won't start: .hhvm.hhbc: No rows in main.GlobalData

Tags: hhvm

HHVM was working normally for some time. I stopped it and tried to restart it. It doesn't start and this error is now present:

```
Failed to load Repo::GlobalData:
  /home/nginx/.hhvm.hhbc: No rows in main.GlobalData_a09f6a0c48ff27570d137b5ceb3ecbb249a51518. Did you forget to compile that file with this HHVM version?
```

Here are the contents of server.ini:

```
hhvm.pid_file = "/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.pid"
hhvm.server.port = 9002
hhvm.server.fix_path_info = true
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.enable_magic_quotes_gpc = false
hhvm.server.enable_keep_alive = true
hhvm.server.enable_ssl = true
hhvm.log.access_log_default_format = "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = Warning
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/access.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/cache/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc.sq3
hhvm.server.apc.enable_apc = true
hhvm.server.apc.shm_size=512M
hhvm.server.apc.num_files_hint=10000
hhvm.server.apc.user_entries_hint=10000
hhvm.server.apc.max_file_size=5M
hhvm.server.apc.enable_cli=1
hhvm.server.request_timeout_seconds = 120
hhvm.server.user = nginx
hhvm.mysql.slow_query_threshold = 10000
hhvm.jit = true
hhvm.jit_asize = 536870912
hhvm.jit_global_data_size = 536870912
hhvm.jit_acold_size = 536870912
hhvm.jit_afrozen_size = 201326592
hhvm.eval.perf_pid_map = false
hhvm.authoritative_mode = true
hhvm.debugger.enable_debugger = false
hhvm.jit_a_hot_size = 512M
hhvm.repo.authoritative = true
hhvm.server.gzip_compression_level = 1
date.timezone = Europe/Dublin   
default_socket_timeout = 120
memory_limit = 512M
```

I've checked the permissions on /var/run/hhvm, /var/cache/hhvm and /home/nginx. It is able to write to all of them, and, upon clearing the hhbc file, it is recreated up to 27kb.

The HHVM log file shows:

```
BootTimer: mapping self...
BootTimer: mapping self block done, took 32336194ns
BootTimer: pagein_self done, took 32356440ns
BootTimer: loading static content...
BootTimer: loading static content block done, took 7879ns
BootTimer: pthread_init done, took 1044896ns
BootTimer: Process::InitProcessStatics done, took 11463ns
BootTimer: timezone_init done, took 8246ns
BootTimer: xenon done, took 2729651ns
BootTimer: ClassInfo::Load done, took 450582ns
BootTimer: pcre_reinit done, took 1769157ns
BootTimer: onig_init done, took 13320ns
BootTimer: xmlInitParser done, took 62395ns
```

I'm looking for some help getting HHVM to start. I would guess that it's unable to compile something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure HHVM is stopped (No zombie process)
remove /home/nginx/.hhvm.hhbc
Change in your server.ini :

```
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/cache/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc.sq3
```

by

```
hhvm.repo.central.path = /home/nginx/hhvm.hhbc
```

Restart

Maybe 2 things :

- you should move from port to socket (better perf !)
- upgrade to hhvm 3.11.1